# Is it possible to suspend/pause the Safari download queue?

Tags: safari

MacOS Monterey, 12.2.1.

I'm wondering if it's possible to 'suspend' or 'pause' Safari's download queue, in a similar way to a printer's queue.

In other words, files wouldn't actually start downloading until the queue was 'resumed'.

Note: I am not talking about suspending one particular file in the queue that is already downloading. I want to stop new files added to the queue from starting to download in the first place.

I'm traversing a website where files automatically download as soon as the page is rendered, and I want to prevent that.

If it's not possible in Safari, all recommendations for third-party utilities, other browsers, paid or otherwise, are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the best possible help is going to **Safari Preferences** > **Websites** > **Downloads** and changing the download permission to **Ask**.